# How can I overload the + operator on String in dart?

Tags: dart

I tried to overload the + operator on the String class to be able to add an int to a String. 'A'+1 should produce 'B'. But it does not work in dartpad. How can I make it work?

```
extension StringExt on String {
  String operator +(int i) {
    return String.fromCharCode(this.codeUnitAt(0) + i);
  }
}

void main() {
  String s = 'A';
  print('A' + 1);
}
```

Comment: You can't overload functions in Dart. So you'd have to pick another name in your extension than `operator +`. I'd say that is better for readability as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! That was very valuable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an extension method named `+` on `String` since `String` already has an operator named `+`.

Dart can only have one member with each name on each class (no member *overloading*), and extension members have lower priority than existing instance members.

You can actually call the extension `+`, but you need to explicitly invoke the extension to avoid `String.operator+` taking precedence:

```dart
 print(StringExt('A') + 1);
```

That removes most of the advantage of having a short operator.

As mentioned, you can use a different name:

```dart
extension CharCodeInc on String {
  String operator /(int i) => String.fromCharCode(codeUnitAt(0) + i);
}
...
  print("A"/2); // prints "C"
```

Too bad all the good names are taken (at least `+` and `*` on strings).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that really clarified my understanding!